# Filling in the area under a normal distribution curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color, statistics

[image]

I'm trying to fill the area between the two $z$-scores but I'm not having any luck. Could someone please help me with this?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  no markers, 
  domain=0:6, 
  samples=100,
  ymin=0,
  axis lines*=left, 
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
  height=5cm, 
  width=12cm,
  xtick=\empty, 
  ytick=\empty,
  enlargelimits=false, 
  clip=false, 
  axis on top,
  grid = major,
  hide y axis
  ]
 \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(x, 3, 1)};

\pgfmathsetmacro\valueB{gauss(1,1,7)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\valueA{gauss(1,1,1.7)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\valueC{gauss(1,1,1)}

\draw [very thick, red]  (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:1,\valueB);
\draw [very thick, red]  (axis cs:2,0) -- (axis cs:2,\valueA);
\draw [very thick, red]  (axis cs:3,0) -- (axis cs:3,\valueC);

\node[below] at (axis cs:3, 0)  {$\mu$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs: 2, 0) {$z=-1.8$};
\node[below] at (axis cs: 1,0) {$z=-2.97$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if turned your code into a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass`. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't know. I will try to do that in the future thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Adding

```
\addplot [draw=none, fill=yellow!25, domain=1:2] {gauss(x, 3, 1)} \closedcycle;
```

*before* your `\addplot` should do it.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-func}
\usepackage{xfp}

% constants
\newcommand*\constA{\fpeval{round(1/\Sigma,2)}}
\newcommand*\constB{\fpeval{round(2*\Sigma^2,2)}}

% function
\def\Gauss[#1,#2]#3{\fpeval{1/(sqrt(2*pi)*#2)*exp(-(#3-#1)^2/(2*#2^2))}}

% labels
\newcommand*\LabelA[1]{%
  \psline(#1,-0.02)(#1,0.02)
  \uput[90](\fpeval{#1-0.25},0.25){\footnotesize $z = #1$}
  \psline[linewidth = 0.02]{->}(\fpeval{#1-0.25},0.25)(#1,0)}
\newcommand*\LabelB[1]{%
  \psline(#1,-0.02)(#1,0.02)
  \uput[90](\fpeval{#1+0.25},0.25){\footnotesize $z = #1$}
  \psline[linewidth = 0.02]{->}(\fpeval{#1+0.25},0.25)(#1,0)}

% settings
\psset{
  xunit = 2,
  yunit = 5
}

% parameters
\def\Mue{2.5}
\def\Sigma{0.44}
\def\pointA{1.5}
\def\pointB{2.2}


\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.35,-0.1)(5.05,1.2)
  \pscustom[linestyle = none, fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = red!80]{%
    \psline(\pointA,0)(\pointA,\Gauss[\Mue,\Sigma]{\pointA})
    \psGauss[mue = \Mue, sigma = \Sigma]{\pointA}{\pointB}
    \psline(\pointB,\Gauss[\Mue,\Sigma]{\pointB})(\pointB,0)}
  \psaxes[Dx = 0.5, Dy = 0.2]{->}(0,0)(0,0)(4.9,1.1)[$z$,0][$P(z)$,90]
  \psline[linecolor = red!80](\Mue,\Gauss[\Mue,\Sigma]{\Mue})(\Mue,0)
  \psGauss[mue = \Mue, sigma = \Sigma, linecolor = blue!80]{0.25}{4.75}
%  \rput(\fpeval{\Mue+1.3},\fpeval{\Gauss[\Mue,\Sigma]{\Mue}-0.1}){%
%    $(\mu,\sigma) = (\Mue,\Sigma)$}
  \rput(\Mue,\fpeval{\Gauss[\Mue,\Sigma]{\Mue}+0.2}){%
    $P(z) = {\displaystyle\frac{\constA}{\sqrt{2\pi}}}
             \exp{\mkern -8mu}\left(-\frac{(z-\Mue)^{2}}{\constB}\right)$}
  \LabelA{\pointA}
  \LabelB{\pointB}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative is the use of `scope` environment via `\clip` command.

```
\begin{scope}[yshift=-\pgflinewidth]
\clip (axis cs:1,0) rectangle (axis cs:2,0.24);
\addplot [draw=none,fill=blue] {gauss(x, 3, 1)};
\end{scope}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
\pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)^2)/(2*#3^2))}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  no markers, 
  domain=0:6, 
  samples=100,
  ymin=0,
  axis lines*=left, 
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
  height=5cm, 
  width=12cm,
  xtick=\empty, 
  ytick=\empty,
  enlargelimits=false, 
  clip=false, 
  axis on top,
  grid = major,
  hide y axis
  ]

\begin{scope}[yshift=-\pgflinewidth]
\clip (axis cs:1,0) rectangle (axis cs:2,0.24);
\addplot [draw=none,fill=blue] {gauss(x, 3, 1)};
\end{scope}

\addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(x, 3, 1)};
\pgfmathsetmacro\valueB{gauss(1,1,7)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\valueA{gauss(1,1,1.65)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\valueC{gauss(1,1,1)}

\draw [very thick, red]  (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:1,\valueB);
\draw [very thick, red]  (axis cs:2,0) -- (axis cs:2,\valueA);
\draw [very thick, red]  (axis cs:3,0) -- (axis cs:3,\valueC);

\node[below] at (axis cs:3,0)  {$\mu$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:2,0) {$z=-1.8$};
\node[below] at (axis cs:1,0) {$z=-2.97$};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```