# setting a normal distribution over a graph's node using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles

I would like to add a [normal distribution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164440/filling-in-the-area-under-a-normal-distribution-curve) inside a circle node using `tikz` package

```
\node[scale=4,circle, fill=blue!55!cyan!25] (Og1) at (0,0) {};
```

The area under the plot would be coloured if it is possible only the horizontal axis will appear without any ticks inside the node.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `path picture`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[circle,draw,minimum size=4cm,path picture={
 \draw[fill=blue] let 
 \p1=($(path picture bounding box.north east)-(path picture bounding box.south
  west)$)
  in plot[variable=\t,domain=-1:1,smooth] 
  ({\t*\x1/2},{exp(-\t*\t)}) |- (-\x1,0)
  (-0.5*\x1,0) edge[-stealth] (0.48*\x1,0)
   (0,0) edge[-stealth] (0,0.48*\y1);
 }]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how is it possible to give the exact coordinate of the node because I have like a graph and I must define the position of the node correctly? Also how can I remove the beginning of arrow from horizontal axis?

Comment: @Dalek The node can be place with `at (0,0)`, say, as in your code. The arrows are due to `(-0.5*\x1,0) edge[-stealth] (0.48*\x1,0)
   (0,0) edge[-stealth] (0,0.48*\y1)`, where `\x1` is and `\y1` are the horizontal and vertical dimension of the bounding box, and equal two times the radius for a circle.

Comment: I tried to resize your answer it gets messed up.

Comment: @Dalek Too bad. You post a short code fragment, get an answer that contains a complete code, you modify the code in a way that you do not specify and then get a mess. Sorry to hear that but there is nothing I can do.